# C3.js chart issue when using an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3.js

I am trying to build a stacked bar chart using c3.js and if i use static data I get the results I want perfectly.

However, the issue I have is when I try and use a dynamic set of data I get no results back

Two fiddles showing one that works and one that doesent.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
data: {
        x: 'x',
    columns: [
            ['x','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct',],
        ['Complete', 7,5,11,8,5],
        ['Incomplete', 5,11,11,6,5  ]

    ],
    type: 'bar',
    groups: [
        ['Complete', 'Incomplete']
    ]
},
axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category'
            }
        },
grid: {
    y: {
        lines: [{value:0}]
    }
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SimonPrice/hdzjefyy/8/ -- Static Data

```
var months = new Array();
months.push('x');
months.push('June');
months.push('July');
months.push('August');
months.push('September');
months.push('October');

var complete = new Array();
complete.push('Complete');
complete.push(5);
complete.push(11);
complete.push(11);
complete.push(6);
complete.push(6);

var incomplete = new Array();
incomplete.push('Incomplete');
incomplete.push(7);
incomplete.push(5);
incomplete.push(11);
incomplete.push(8);
incomplete.push(5);

console.log(months);
console.log(complete);
console.log(incomplete);


var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
data: {
        x: 'x',
    columns: [
            [months],
        [complete],
        [incomplete]

    ],
    type: 'bar',
    groups: [
        ['Complete', 'Incomplete']
    ]
},
axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category'
            }
        },
grid: {
    y: {
        lines: [{value:0}]
    }
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SimonPrice/hdzjefyy/7/ -- Data from Array

I am unsure \ unclear on why this would be different and why this isnt working. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add `months`, `complete` and `incomplete` in an array inside `columns`. It is already an array. Remove, it and code will work.

```js
var months = new Array();
months.push('x');
months.push('June');
months.push('July');
months.push('August');
months.push('September');
months.push('October');

var complete = new Array();
complete.push('Complete');
complete.push(5);
complete.push(11);
complete.push(11);
complete.push(6);
complete.push(6);

var incomplete = new Array();
incomplete.push('Incomplete');
incomplete.push(7);
incomplete.push(5);
incomplete.push(11);
incomplete.push(8);
incomplete.push(5);


var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart1',
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      months,
      complete,
      incomplete
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    groups: [
      ['Complete', 'Incomplete']
    ]
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'category'
    }
  },
  grid: {
    y: {
      lines: [{
        value: 0
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
```

Comment: I just looked at my issue again after leaving it and came to the same answer, but as you have taken the time to provide an answer I will mark it correct. Thanks